# Getting steps from healthkit which was written by other applications

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Let's say we have some steps data in healthkit which was auto detected by iphone and written to healthkit. And we have some steps data was enetred by user manually. Now I can differentiate between these steps using this code

```
let type = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount) // The type of data we are requesting

    let date = NSDate()
    let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let newDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(date)
    print(newDate)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(newDate, endDate: NSDate(), options: .None) // Our search predicate which will fetch all steps taken today

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: type!, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil) { query, results, error in
        var steps: Double = 0

        //if result.metadata!["HKWasUserEntered"]! == 1{
        if results?.count > 0
        {
            for result in results as! [HKQuantitySample]
            {
                print("Steps \(result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))")
                print()
                // checking and truncating manually added steps
                if result.metadata != nil {

                }
                else{
                    steps += result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())
                }

            }
            print(steps)
        }

        completion(steps, error)
        //}
    }

    executeQuery(query)
```

But Lets say if some other app writes some some step's data to healthkit like some fitness app.

[image]

Now I am able to read steps with device icon(auto recorded), but
 How can I read steps with UP icon as well ?

(UP) is and fitness application by JawBone.

Comment: you are use CMPedometer library

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMPedometer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMPedometer/startPedometerUpdatesFromDate:withHandler:

Comment: Are you sure ? this is what I am looking for ?

Comment: yes, you are search CMPedometer example availble.

Comment: It seems something different to me. for fotching any thing from healthit I am using healthit clases why use something else ?

Comment: health kit some after data give than CMPedometer is fastest data fetch compare to health kit.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to get diffentiate data between steps on the base of source ?